# LinkedIn - Access

Tags: linkedin-api

A few years ago I signed up as a LinkedIn developer, registered an application and received my Client ID and Secret.
Using OAuth2, when I attempt to get an access token I get an error message saying "OAuth2 access is denied."
I've checked all the settings in my developer account and cannot see anything wrong, so I don't know why access is denied.

Comment: I discovered that I needed to untick all of the Default Application Permissions with the exception of "r_basicprofile". I no longer get the OAuth2 access denied error.

Comment: You can post your solution as answer to your own question instead of a comment. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: thanks Adrian, I've now posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: I discovered that if I untick all of the Default Application Permissions with the exception of "r_basicprofile", I no longer get the OAuth2 access denied error.